# Добавление материала в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на CMS WordPress, он работает на локальном сервере через XAMPP. Как можно добавлять материалы на сайт, чтобы его видели другие пользователи?

Comment: Другие пользователи это какие? В Вашей локальной сети или пользователи всея Интернета?

Comment: Открывать сайт для других пользователей - это значит открывать свой компьтер. + нагружать его безмерно. Стоит 1005000 раз подумать - нужно ли это делать. Для этого существуют хостинги.

Comment: Ну, чтобы все пользователи видели запись.

Comment: Ну, к примеру, у меня есть сайт-блог, и в нем должны быть блоги, и как мне добавить на сайт (на определенную страницу) запись, чтобы потом другие пользователи видели мой блог/запись ?

Comment: Я знаю, что в WordPress есть редактор, в котором я могу прописать текст и добавить ее на сайт, но я хочу узнать, как можно так сделать, чтобы моя запись публиковалось не на странице Home (домашняя страница), а на странице Blog (страница, где должны быть добавлены разного рода Тексты/Блоги) ?